# yepnope.js injecting scripts above already loaded scripts

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

I'm using yepnope with modernizr and drupal 7. I already have scripts (jquery, drupal.js, etc.) loading without yepnope. When I use yepnope and modernizr to inject a script conditionally it injects above all the other scripts, including jquery. Is there a way to inject scripts after all other scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

> yepnope.js always executes things in the order they are listed

So you could just load all your scripts through yepnope,

```
yepnope([{
   load : ['jquery', 'drupal']
}]);
 yepnope([{
   //Conditional scripts.
}]);
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But I'm looking for a way to do it without having to load everything through yepnope.